# shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, typeerror, data-analysis

I want to combine sheets of given file but my code gives me given type error
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

```
`import pandas as pd
wb_url = r'D:\DA\power query data\Excel Power Query Practice 
Material\36. Power Query - Append                    Queries\Append 
Queries\Yearly Data - Tables - Quick Method.xlsx'

excel_file = pd.read_excel(wb_url, sheet_name=None)
combined_df = pd.concat(excel_file)`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems: `excel_file` is a dictionary that maps each sheet name to a DataFrame so we need to unpack excel_file before we use it, and `pd.concat` takes a sequence of objects (e.g. a list of DataFrames)

Using a sample excel file (consisting of three sheets with columns called `a` and `b`), we can do something like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
for sheet_name, sheet_df in excel_file.items():
    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, sheet_df])
```

Result:

```
>>> combined_df
     a     b
0  1.0  10.0
1  2.0  20.0
2  3.0  30.0
0  4.0  40.0
1  5.0  50.0
2  6.0  60.0
0  7.0  70.0
1  8.0  80.0
2  9.0  90.0
```

Note: you can also reset the index if you like, but for the purpose of this demonstration, I want it to be clear where the data from each sheet comes from